# Unable to suppress messages from knitr

Tags: r, knitr

The following code still results in

````
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
rm(list=ls())
library(randomForest)
library(tree)
library(ggplot2)
```
````

the following -- how can I suppress the following?

```
## randomForest 4.6-12

## Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.

##
## Attaching package:'ggplot2'

## The following object is masked from'package:randomForest':
##
##     margin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's best to avoid blanket suppression of messages or warnings because its very easy to miss real issues that you *do* want to be warned about. I recommend disabling package load messages selectively on each package load. This way if you add a new package to your library list, you will see any errors or messages that are generated and have the choice to suppress them or deal with them in another way.

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
rm(list=ls())
suppressMessages(library(randomForest))
library(tree)
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
```
````

Comment: In general, one should be careful when suppressing _warnings_, but I think messages are typically safe to be suppressed by definition (if they are really important, authors should use `warning()` instead), especially package startup messages. `suppressMessages()` may appear to be surprising and attract unnecessary attention from those who do not know it. In all, I think you have a point, but I would use the chunk option `message=FALSE` in this case for cleaner code.

Comment: In theory I agree with you, and in python this is usually my stance. But with R, I've seen lots of "messages" from package loads that I would consider a warning, not a message. I choose to approach them all as if they were all warnings. But it does make the code really ugly; I'm still trying to figure out a way to make that cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `message=FALSE`:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

If that doesn't work, the package author is (incorrectly) using something other than `message()` for messages.